Graphing the rational function $f(x)=\frac{3x}{x^2+x-2}$

Hello all, I was working through this problem and I tried it myself. I found the asymptotes, and due to the rule, the vertical ones are at $x = -2$ and $x = 1$, and the horizontal should be at $y = 0$. But once I checked my solution, the graph did not seem to have an asymptote near $y = 0$. In fact, part of the graph passes right through it. Oddly, could you please help me out?

If polynomial in the denominator has higher power then the one in the numerator, a rational function has a horizontal asymptote $y=0$. That because as $x$ goes to infinity, $y$ goes to zero. One common misconception is that a graph cannot cross horizontal asymptote. That is not true.

Intuitively and loosely speaking, we said $y=0$ is an asymptote to the graph of $f(x)$ means the behaviour of $f$ at (one of the) infinity are approximately similar to $y=0$, so it is possible to cut through it, because asymptotes only care about the tail of the graph. Also, in your graph, their $y$ are going closely to $0$ as $x$ increases, it matches with your investigation on horizontal asymptote.

hello all thanks fo rate help I have one question though, for the definition I have studied of asymptotes is that they are the lines that a graph of a fucntion approaches but never actually touched but in this case the functions I s touching them, is there something I am missing? Thanks for all the help and please put your answer as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!!!
